# Cannot deserialize instance of `model.UsersPajo` out of START_ARRAY token at [Source: (String)"[UsersPajo{website='hildegard.org'

Tags: java, json, jackson

I can’t understand why deserialization doesn’t work.

```
public static String readUserFile(String titleFile) {
    String pathJSONFile = "src/main/resources/" + titleFile + ".json";
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    File jsonFile = new File(pathJSONFile);
    UsersPajo[] usersPajos2= null;

    try {
        usersPajos2 = objectMapper.readValue(jsonFile, UsersPajo[].class);
        System.out.println("_usersPajos2___" + usersPajos2);
    } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    String information = Arrays.toString(usersPajos2);

    try {
        usersPajo = objectMapper.readValue(information, UsersPajo.class);
    } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
    }
```

I've already tried various options, but it looks like I'm confused.Here is the mistake.

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize instance of 
`model.UsersPajo` out of START_ARRAY token
at [Source: (String)"[UsersPajo{website='hildegard.org', address=Address{zipcode='92998- 
3874', geo=Geo{lng='81.1496', lat='-37.3159'}, suite='Apt. 556', city='Gwenborough', 
street='Kulas Light'}, phone='1-770-736-8031 x56442', name='Leanne Graham', 
company=Company{bs='harness real-time e-markets', catchPhrase='Multi-layered client-server 
neural-net', name='Romaguera-Crona'}, id=1, email='Sincere@april.biz', username='Bret'}, 
UsersPajo{website='anastasia.net', address=Address{zipcode='90566-7771', 
geo=Geo{lng='-34.46"[truncated 3643 chars]; line: 1, column: 1]
at
```

Here is the class model

```
public class UsersPajo{
private String website;
private Address address;
private String phone;
private String name;
private Company company;
private int id;
private String email;
private String username;

public String getWebsite(){
    return website;
}

public Address getAddress(){
    return address;
}

public String getPhone(){
    return phone;
}

public String getName(){
    return name;
}

public Company getCompany(){
    return company;
}

public int getId(){
    return id;
}

public String getEmail(){
    return email;
}

public String getUsername(){
    return username;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "UsersPajo{" +
            "website='" + website + '\'' +
            ", address=" + address +
            ", phone='" + phone + '\'' +
            ", name='" + name + '\'' +
            ", company=" + company +
            ", id=" + id +
            ", email='" + email + '\'' +
            ", username='" + username + '\'' +
            '}';
         }
       }
```

My JSON file

```
[ {
 "id" : 1,
 "name" : "Leanne Graham",
 "username" : "Bret",
 "email" : "Sincere@april.biz",
  "address" : {
     "street" : "Kulas Light",
     "suite" : "Apt. 556",
     "city" : "Gwenborough",
     "zipcode" : "92998-3874",
     "geo" : {
     "lat" : "-37.3159",
     "lng" : "81.1496"
    }
   },
 "phone" : "1-770-736-8031 x56442",
 "website" : "hildegard.org",
 "company" : {
    "name" : "Romaguera-Crona",
    "catchPhrase" : "Multi-layered client-server neural-net",
    "bs" : "harness real-time e-markets"
   }
}, ...
]
```

I read information from a file and then write it into a string. After that, I want to get my java object from this line using desrialization. Tell me why desirialization does not work? What needs to be fixed

Comment: Can you share the content of your JSON file? It does not seem right. Thanks!

Comment: shared my JSON file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is the following lines of code:

```java
try {
    usersPajo = objectMapper.readValue(information, UsersPajo.class);
} catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

The variable `information` contains the following:

```
[UsersPajo{website='hildegard.org', address=Address{zipcode='92998- 
3874', geo=Geo{lng='81.1496', lat='-37.3159'}, suite='Apt. 556', city='Gwenborough', 
street='Kulas Light'}, phone='1-770-736-8031 x56442', name='Leanne Graham', 
company=Company{bs='harness real-time e-markets', catchPhrase='Multi-layered client-server 
neural-net', name='Romaguera-Crona'}, id=1, email='Sincere@april.biz', username='Bret'}, 
UsersPajo{website='anastasia.net', address=Address{zipcode='90566-7771', 
geo=Geo{lng='-34.46"....
```

Which basically is the `usersPajos2` mapped to a String. This obviously can't be deserialized into a single `UsersPajo` instance. So get rid of these lines of code and keep all others:

```java
public static String readUserFile(String titleFile) {
    String pathJSONFile = "src/main/resources/" + titleFile + ".json";
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    File jsonFile = new File(pathJSONFile);
    UsersPajo[] usersPajos2= null;

    try {
        usersPajos2 = objectMapper.readValue(jsonFile, UsersPajo[].class);
        System.out.println("_usersPajos2___" + usersPajos2);
    } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return Arrays.toString(usersPajos2);
}
```

Comment: And how do I then convert this string to a Java object?

Comment: But why do you want to convert that string into a Java object? You have an array of `UsersPajo` that you convert into a `String`. Why do you want to get them back if you already have them in `usersPajos2 `?

Comment: I need to transform this string into UsersPajo.class

Comment: You already have a bunch of `UsersPajo` in `usersPajos2` that you for some reason convert into a `String`.

Comment: I have JSON written to a file. Now I need to read this file and transform it into a java object. So that I can then compare this object with another.

Comment: But you are doing that already in `usersPajos2 = objectMapper.readValue(jsonFile, UsersPajo[].class);`. `usersPajos2` is an array of `UsersPajo` objects. You have the objects already.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239218/discussion-between---and-joao-dias).